# DbSet Ordering by non primitive field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm trying to implement an sorting table in MVC with Razor but i'm having such a pain to make the sorting work with some fields which are non primitive. My class model is as follows

```
public class Turma
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Ano { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Professor")]
    public int Professor_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Disciplina")]
    public int Disciplina_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Disciplina Disciplina { get; set; }
}

public class Professor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
}

public class Disciplina
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

I'm tring to, with an DbSet, sorting it like this:

```
turmas = turmas.OrderByDescending(s => s.Disciplina.Nome);
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: I assume you're joining the associated tables on in your query? (`Include()`).. ?

Comment: Yes. Did you try that?